# Fourier Transform for speech signal

Tags: matlab, fft, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, speech

I need some clue on how to apply the Fourier transform to a wideband discrete signal like speech in Matlab. What I want to do is to apply the MUSIC algorithm to the speech recorded by a set of microphones and in order to do that I need to take the FFT and then apply the MUSIC algorithm to the bins of frequencies which now I consider them narrowband .

Comment: Hi @zahraesb, welcome to DSP.SE. If you could edit your question to provide some more details about what you're trying to accomplish by applying the FT, we can re-open this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the samples of the speech satisfying Nyquist criterion.  Say you got a vector of samples called x.  spectrogram(x) would give you the short time Fourier Transform of x.  fft(x) would give you the dft of the speech signal in a more computation-efficient manner compared to direct computation.

Please visit

http://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html

Also see help fft and choose whatever you want.